# Creating a WPF control that uses datatemplates

Tags: wpf, vb.net, custom-controls, datatemplate

I'm trying to build a control that will display items in a sort of scheduling grid, so that they are placed horizontally depending on what category their in, and vertically depending on what time they are scheduled and how much time the item will take to complete. I am currently inheriting from System.Windows.Controls.Control and the default style and template is shown below:

```
    <Style TargetType="KHS:TimeGrid">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="KHS:TimeGrid">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Grid Name="PART_HeaderGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TimeColumn}"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid>

                                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                    <Grid Name="PART_BodyGrid">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Name="TimeColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

For my items, I simply use this interface:

```
Public Interface ITimeGridItem
    Property StartTime As Date
    Property Duration As TimeSpan
End Interface
```

Rows are added to the "BodyGrid" for each increment of time (representing 15 minutes by default) and items are given Grid.Row and Grid.RowSpan values based on their start times and durations.

My problem comes in when I try to implement DataTemplates for items. I'm currently trying to use ContentPresenters to display the items. It would be easy to create an ItemTemplate property for the TimeGrid and just use it for all items, but what if I need to template items of different types with unique templates?

That got me thinking how other controls can have DataTemplates added to their Resources collection with different DataTypes, and the control knows to search the resources and pick the right template. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to implement that. Anyone know how I can accomplish this? It must be possible since Microsoft does it in their controls.

Comment: "Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to implement that" -- that's because they don't implement it. It just happens. If an implicit DataTemplate is in scope, it's used. I just toss stuff in ContentControls and it works. Try it, I bet it'll work.

Comment: As a direction, look into System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector. It might hold the key to what you want. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god I can't believe it was so simple. I actually have to give some credit to @ed-plunkett for his all-to-obvious comment. I looked a bit harder and by accident discovered that if I changed this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="local:TestItem">
```

to this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestItem}">
```

it works!

A few minutes later, I found this article:
http://briannoyesblog.azurewebsites.net/2013/11/23/use-xtype-with-wpf-implicit-datatemplates

*sigh* I wish I had found that earlier.

So as long as I use the {x:Type} syntax I can put the DataTemplate anywhere in the scope and it will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your specific implementation to give you an exact answer but I'd probably look into using a wrapper control that you apply your custom template to and then place a ContentControl within it that renders the child view with whatever they've been templated with themselves.

To be honest though I wouldn't use a grid for something like this, the way I've done it in the past is with data binding. Create a view model for all the items you want to display and give it X and Y properties. Then in your XAML draw them all with a single ItemsControl that has a Canvas as its background and binds the item's Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left dp's to the X and Y's. That way your view model code has complete freedom to position the children exactly where you want them and you can also unit-test without having to invoke the view classes themselves. Once I stopped trying to be overly-clever with XAML, and just stuck to using it for loosely coupled data-binding, complex GUI designs suddenly became very easy to implement.